# Contenteditable="true" и обвёртка, как в bb кодах

Tags: contenteditable, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/

Выделите например "текст" и нажмите на "Вставить тег". 
Почему вместо того, чтобы выделилось слово "текст" тегами `<b></b>`, добавляются по бокам ещё слова "текст"? Для textarea этот код работает отлично, а вот для div с `contenteditable="true"` нет :(

При выделении должно быть так:

> `<b> текст </b>`

, а выходит так:

> `текст <b> текст </b> текст`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновлено:

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();

var tagname = $(open + close);
tagname[0].appendChild(selectedText);
selection.insertNode(tagname[0]);

if (selectedText.childNodes[1] != undefined){
    console.log(selectedText.childNodes[1]);
    $(selectedText.childNodes[1]).remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/4/

Comment: @lampa, Вы не совсем меня поняли. Неправильно выделяется текст. 

http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/ Вы протестируйте, как работает выделение вообще. Тегами обводит, да. text - для теста, чтобы видеть. Но при выделении должно быть так: >> <b> текст </b>, а выходит так: >>текст <b> текст </b> текст

Comment: О, сори! 

Юзай window.getSelection(); Я сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: @lampa, вот уже лучше. Хоть выделенные буквы обрамляет в теги. Но если выделить весь текст, то опять проблема. http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/1/

Comment: @ModaL переделал.

Comment: @lampa, перевел Вам 250 очков за то, что помогаете :) Но вот ещё смотрите, http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/2/ попробуйте выделить "ещё текст", он не выделится и + убьётся перенос строк...

Comment: @ModaL в интернете рассказывают, что можно решить всё иначе: http://jsfiddle.net/FLwxj/61/ Твой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/88NAw/4/

Comment: @lampa, спасибо, умный Вы человек. +100 ещё к Вашей репутации. Очень сильно помогли!